# connection between opnet and c program

Tags: c

I write this project but there are some error

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "C:\OPNET\14.5.A\sys\include\esa.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int total_pk_num = 0;
int total_size = 0;
static void notification_callback(void *state, double time, void *value);
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    EsaT_State_Handle esa_handle;
    int evt_num;
    double ret_time;
    EsaT_Interface *interfaces;
    EsaT_Interface inf_size;
    EsaT_Interface inf_desc;
    int num;
    int status;
    int i = 0;
    char desc[256];

    Esa_Main(argc, argv, ESAC_OPTS_NONE);
    Esa_Init(argc, argv, ESAC_OPTS_NONE, &esa_handle);
    Esa_Load(esa_handle, ESAC_OPTS_NONE);
    Esa_Interface_Group_Get(esa_handle, &interfaces, &num);

    inf_size = interfaces[0];
    inf_desc = interfaces[1];

    Esa_Interface_Callback_Register(esa_handle, &status, inf_size, notification_callback, 0, 0);

    while(1)
    {
        printf("External program\n");

        Esa_Execute_Until(esa_handle, &status, 10*++i, 
            ESAC_UNTIL_INCLUSIVE, &ret_time, &evt_num);

        if(status == ESAC_STATUS_TERMINATION)
        {
            printf("Simulation finished\n");
            break;
        }

        Esa_Interface_Value_Get(esa_handle, &status, inf_desc, &desc);      
        printf("%s\n\n\n", desc);

        sprintf(desc, "No. of packets: %d - time: %f (set in external program)", 
            total_pk_num, ret_time);
        Esa_Interface_Value_Set(
            esa_handle, &status, inf_desc, ESAC_NOTIFY_IMMEDIATELY, &desc);
    }

    return 0;
}


void notification_callback(void *state, double time, void *value)
{   
    printf("Total packet number: %d, total size: %d bits\n", 
        ++total_pk_num, total_size += *(int *)value);

    return;
}
```

***this program have a lot of problems ,although this code don't have any error    ,because I copy it from book . I try to connect opnet with C program this errors appear ***

```
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winnt.h(6361): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'ContextRecord'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winnt.h(6361): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winnt.h(6361): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winnt.h(12983): error C2065: 'PCONTEXT' : undeclared identifier
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winnt.h(12984): error C2146: syntax error : missing ')' before identifier 'ContextRecord'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winnt.h(12984): warning C4229: anachronism used : modifiers on data are ignored
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winnt.h(12984): error C2182: 'RtlCaptureContext' : illegal use of type 'void'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winnt.h(12984): error C2491: 'RtlCaptureContext' : definition of dllimport data not allowed
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winnt.h(12984): error C2059: syntax error : ')'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winnt.h(13372): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '__stdcall'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winnt.h(13372): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winnt.h(13376): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winnt.h(14982): error C3861: '__readfsdword': identifier not found
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winbase.h(1048): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'LPCONTEXT'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winbase.h(1048): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winbase.h(1048): error C2378: 'PCONTEXT' : redefinition; symbol cannot be overloaded with a typedef
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winnt.h(13372) : see declaration of 'PCONTEXT'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winbase.h(1048): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winbase.h(3610): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'PCONTEXT'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winbase.h(4449): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'LPCONTEXT'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winbase.h(4457): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winbase.h(4457): error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before '*'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winbase.h(15112): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '__stdcall'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winbase.h(15112): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winbase.h(15116): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\users\ahmed\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\test_1\test_1\test_1.cpp(37): error C2664: 'Esa_Interface_Callback_Register' : cannot convert parameter 4 from 'void (__cdecl *)(void *,double,void *)' to 'EsaT_Interface_Callback_Proc'
1>          None of the functions with this name in scope match the target type
1>
1>Build FAILED.
1>
1>Time Elapsed 00:00:01.70
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: Did you notice that the error messages are coming from library headers, and mention `C++`? Also: *"Note: C++ does not support default-int"* suggests you aren't declaring the headers properly, that is, have forward references to undefined functions.

Comment: I check the header from more than book .I think the error on paths so please check this file:https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3ZJj0Bq16kMS2FQWjFmcTVSREE/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Your source file is .cpp but you're writing C code.  Change the name of your file to test_1.c

Comment: @AhmedSalem - `c:\users\ahmed\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\test_1\test_1\test_1.cpp(37): error C2664: ........`

Answer (score 0):

You declared `notification_callback` with the following types for its parameters:

```
(void *, double, void *)
```

Looking for esa.h for opnet in Internet (I have found version 10.0.A, but probably that has not changed), the parameters for a `Esa_Interface_Callback_Register` should be:

```
(void *, double, va_list)
```

You could use your function in a similar way, but you should declare it using va_list, and take the first parameter if you know it is the only one that you are going to get.

And also, as KevinDTimm answered, I think it is better to avoid C++ if you are not using it for anything, and just work with plain C.

Comment: Thank you for your efforts , but Please check this path for visual studio and opnet :https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3ZJj0Bq16kMS2FQWjFmcTVSREE/view?usp=sharing  to run co-simulation  I enter this code :   CL /c cosim_external_code1.c /I"C:\OPNET\14.5.A\sys\include”/I"C:\Visual8\VC\PlatformSDK\include"/D_X86_